# Can we write queries in Multichain like select * from Stream1.key1 where key1.value = “xyz”

Tags: blockchain, blockchain.info-api

Can we write queries in Multichain to retrieve conditional data from streams e.g. select * from  Stream1.key1 where key1.value = “xyz”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many different ways of slicing and dicing stream items, but it does not support SQL. I'm not sure what you want to do with this query, but maybe **liststreamkeyitems** is what you're looking for? See the 'Querying subscribed streams' section on this page:

https://www.multichain.com/developers/json-rpc-api/